# Dll code segment sharing between processes

Tags: windows, dll, hook

I read that in Windows, code segment of dll is shared across multiple processes by mapping the same physical address to the virtual addresses of different processes.
So i am a bit confused about what exactly happens when you are doing inline hooking.
For example Kernel32.dll is loaded by almost every process, so if i change the first bytes of ShellExecute in one process it should affect all other processes which loads that dll. But it looks like that does not happen. My question is, does Windows use something like copy-on-write mechanism when dealing with such situations or it simply does not share the code segment?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, COW is automatic when you call VirtualProtect/Ex() so you can get write access.  A debugger relies on this as well to set a breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!